# SSIS package how to add date/timestamp to file name each time package run

Tags: sql-server, csv, datetime, ssis, etl

i have a SSIS package that outputs a csv file to a location this package will be run on a daily basis.at the moment I look if a file exists and if it does I delete it before creating a new one so that I don't get any errors with creating  a file that already exists - what I want to do is create a new csv and add a date/timestamp to the end of file name. I'm not sure how I go about achieving this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this using the following steps:

1. Add a variable i.e. `User::Filename`
2. Click on the variable, and press F4 to show the properties Tab
3. In the Expression use an expression similar to the following:

   ```
   "C:\\Filename_" + (DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(GETDATE()) + "_" + (DT_WSTR,4)MONTH(GETDATE()) + "_" + (DT_WSTR,4)DAY(GETDATE()) + ".csv"
   ```
4. In the Destination Flat File Connection manager, in the expressions (found in the property tab) use this variable as a Connection String expression

   ```
   @[User::Filename]
   ```

Comment: I'm learning SSIS and this is something that I would like to accomplish. Where, exactly do I do those steps? I have an OLE DB Source that runs a select script, and a Flat File Destination that generates the file from the query.

I assume it's done somewhere in the Flat File Destination, but I'm not seeing where I'd actually add the variable.

Comment: @marky you should add a package variable and evaluate it as the expression I mentioned. Then you should configure the Flat File connection manager to read the "connectionstring" property from the variable you created. Check the following article: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1084/dynamic-flat-file-connections-in-sql-server-integration-services/